# Render view with children

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-view

I have a problem with render a view inside action. Here is my code:

```
public function editUserAction() {
$sideView = new SideViewModel();

$sideView->setHeaderView(new HeaderViewModel(array(
    "title" => 'Editing user',
    "desc" => 'Edit your users or add new',
)));

$sideView->setMiddleView(new HeaderViewModel(array(
    "title" => 'Editing user',
    "desc" => 'Edit your users or add new',
)));

$renderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewRenderer');
$renderer->setCanRenderTrees(true);
$html = $renderer->render($sideView);


exit($html);
return $jsonModel;
}
```

Problem is with render level - now i get rendered $sideView without childs like HeaderViewModel etc.

Here is method setMiddleView:

```
public function setMiddleView($view){
    $this->addChild($view, 'middleView');
}
```

What i doing wrong?

Comment: because i want in JSON send viewModel in html.

Comment: JSON and tree rendering cannot go together. The php renderer can render child models, the JSON renderer cannot. You have to choose either one, but you cannot combine the features from both.